# Proving Asymptotic Equipartition Property for Gaussian r.v.'s using the Chernoff Bound

Tags: inequality, information-theory

I just learned about [Chernoff Bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) and am wondering if one can prove the [Asymptotic Equipartition Property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equipartition_property) using them instead of the [Weak Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) (which is the consequence of the [Chebyshev Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)). I started with a what I thought was a simple case: sequence of i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables $\{X_i\}$ where $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.  We are interested in proving:

$$P\left(\left|-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)-H(X)\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0$$

First step in applying Chernoff Bound is finding the [Moment Generating Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).  However, I ran into trouble immediately:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}E\left[\exp(-t\log(\phi(x))\right]&=&\int e^{-t\log(\phi(x))}\phi(x)dx\\
&=&\int\exp\left(-t\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}\right)\right)\phi(x)dx\\
&=&\int\exp\left(t\left(\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma\right)+x^2/\sigma^2\right)\right)\phi(x)dx\\
&=&\int\frac{\left[2\pi\sigma^2\right]^{\frac{t}{2}}\exp\left(tx^2/\sigma^2\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}dx\\
&=&\int\frac{\left[2\pi\sigma^2\right]^{\frac{t}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2(1-t)}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx\\
&=&?
\end{array}$$
where $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$.  I am stuck because $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus can be greater than one...

What did I do wrong?  Is it even possible to prove AEP using Chernoff Bounds?

Comment: What happened to this question? Are you not interested anymore?

Comment: Sorry, I've been really busy.  Still interested, but haven't had the time to properly digest your answer.

Comment: What specific part is less easy to *digest*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me abstract a little bit the situation and show that the inequality you have in mind stems from a rather general result (as mentioned in the comments, the following should be explained in every introductory text on large deviations principles). Consider some integrable random variables $\xi$ and $(\xi_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ and, for some $n\geqslant1$ and some positive $x$, the event

> $$
> A_n=[\xi_1+\cdots+\xi_n\geqslant n\mathrm E(\xi)+nx].
> $$

Using first $\xi_i=\log\phi(X_i)$ and then $\xi_i=-\log\phi(X_i)$, the event you consider is the union of two events $A_n$, hence our task is to bound $\mathrm P(A_n)$.

Now comes an additional, non trivial, hypothesis: assume that $\xi$ is exponentially integrable, that is:

> $\qquad\qquad$ There exists $t_0\gt0$ such that $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})$ is finite for every $|t|\lt t_0$. $\qquad(\ast)$

Then the proof is simple. Start from the almost sure inequality, valid for every nonnegative $t$:
$$
\mathrm e^{nt(\mathrm E(\xi)+x)}\,\mathbf 1_{A_n}\leqslant\mathrm e^{t(\xi_1+\cdots+\xi_n)}=\mathrm e^{t\xi_1}\cdots\mathrm e^{t\xi_n}.
$$
Integrate both sides and use the independence assumption. This yields
$$
\mathrm e^{nt(\mathrm E(\xi)+x)}\,\mathrm P(A_n)\leqslant\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})^n.
$$
We proved that, for every nonnegative $t$, 
$$
\mathrm P(A_n)\leqslant u(t)^n\qquad\text{where}\qquad u(t)=\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})\mathrm e^{-t(\mathrm E(\xi)+x)}.
$$
Note that a lot of these inequalities are just useless. For example, $u(0)=1$ hence the $t=0$ version is $\mathrm P(A_n)\leqslant 1$... Big deal! Even worse: if $t\gt0$ is such that $u(t)\gt1$, or such that $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})$ is infinite, we painfully proved that $\mathrm P(A_n)$ is bounded by something greater than $1$, or infinite. :-)

On the other hand, if there exists at least some nonnegative $t$ such that $u(t)\lt1$, the inequality becomes a strong control on $\mathrm P(A_n)$, namely, that $\mathrm P(A_n)\to0$ at least as fast as a geometric sequence. Hence the key question becomes:

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad$ Does there exist some $t\gt0$ such that $u(t)\lt1$?

To answer this, let us consider the limit $t\to0$ with $t\gt0$. Then,
$$
\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})=1+t\mathrm E(\xi)+o(t),\qquad
\mathrm e^{-t(\mathrm E(\xi)+x)}=1-t(\mathrm E(\xi)+x)+o(t),
$$
hence $u(t)=1-tx+o(t)$. Since $x\gt0$, this limited expansion implies that $u(t)\lt1$ for (at least) some (small) $t\gt0$. The proof is over.

To sum up, the result stems from a Markov-type inequality plus a limited expansion of the Laplace transform $t\mapsto\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})$ at $t=0$. The Markov-type inequality is powerful because the $\xi_n$ are independent. The limited expansion is valid because we assumed $(\ast)$.

Note that the proof above uses the finiteness of $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})$ for $0\leqslant t\leqslant t_0$ only. The finiteness for $-t_0\leqslant t\leqslant 0$ is needed when dealing with the event $[\xi_1+\cdots+\xi_n\leqslant n\mathrm E(\xi)-nx]$, hence the control $(\ast)$ must indeed be two-sided.

Coming back at last to the question you asked, if $\xi=\log\phi(X)$ with $X$ centered normal of variance $\sigma^2$ and $\phi$ the density of the distribution of $X$, then $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})$ is finite if and only if $\mathrm E(\phi(X)^{t})$ is finite if and only if $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{-tX^2/(2\sigma^2)})$ is finite if and only if $t+1\gt0$, hence $(\ast)$ holds with $t_0=1$.

Comment: I finally was able to properly sit down and read your answer.  Thank you, I think it's clear to me now.  Basically, one *can* use Chernoff Bounds to prove AEP for a limited selection of distributions of the random variables (i.e. when (*) holds).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can use Chernoff bound to prove AEP. We should actually prove $$P\left(\left|-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)-H(X)\right|>\epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0$$
So we should prove both $$P\left(-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)>H(X)+\epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0 \text{ and }P\left(-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)<H(X)-\epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0 $$

Chernoff bound reads, for any $t>0$, $P(X>x)\le e^{-t x} E(e^{t X})$. Your calculation of $E(e^{t \log \phi(X)})$ is correct. This expectation exists for $t<1$.

Now $$P\left(-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)>H(X)+\epsilon\right)\le e^{-nt(H(X)+\epsilon)} \cdot E\left[e^{-t \sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)}\right]$$ where $$E\left[e^{-t\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)}\right]=n\cdot E(e^{-t \log \phi(X)})=\frac{n}{(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma)^{1-t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2(1-t)}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx$$ which is positive for $t<1$. So $$P\left(-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)>H(X)+\epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0$$
But I don't think we can use Chernoff bound to show the other probability also goes to $0$.

Edit:
As Bullmoose requested I will post the reason why Chernoff bound doesn't work to the show the other probability goes to zero.

Chernoff bound in the other case is $P(X<x)\le e^{t x} E(e^{-t X})$. So what I think we would get in the other case is that $$\begin{eqnarray*}P\left(-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)<H(X)-\epsilon\right)&\le& e^{nt(H(X)-\epsilon)} \cdot E\left[e^{t \sum_{i=1}^n\log \phi(X_i)}\right]\\ &=& e^{nt(H(X)-\epsilon)} \cdot\frac{n}{(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma)^{1+t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2(1+t)}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx\end{eqnarray*} $$
and the right hand side goes to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$ for $\epsilon<H(X)$.

Comment: I think we can use it, the trick is keeping $H(X)$ on the LHS in the probability statement.  Thank you for inspiring me, I've posted my own answer which I probably wouldn't have figured out without your attempt.

Comment: My comment on Bullmoose's answer applies to this one as well.